# TensorBoard failed to create session

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Hello

I'm using TensorFlow v 1.4.0 and when I want to create a TensorBoard session with the following commands:

```
tensorboard --logdir="folder_path"
```

I have an error:

```
2018-04-11 17:18:44.422839: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1344] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: TITAN Xp major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:02:00.0
totalMemory: 11,91GiB freeMemory: 11,74GiB
2018-04-11 17:18:44.467559: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:167] Internal: failed initializing StreamExecutor for CUDA device ordinal 1: Internal: failed call to cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain: CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_DEVICE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/tensorboard", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run_main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorboard/main.py", line 36, in run_main
    tf.app.run(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorboard/main.py", line 45, in main
    default.get_assets_zip_provider())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorboard/program.py", line 166, in main
    tb = create_tb_app(plugins, assets_zip_provider)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorboard/program.py", line 200, in create_tb_app
    window_title=FLAGS.window_title)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 124, in standard_tensorboard_wsgi
    plugin_instances = [constructor(context) for constructor in plugins]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 124, in <listcomp>
    plugin_instances = [constructor(context) for constructor in plugins]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorboard/plugins/beholder/beholder_plugin.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.most_recent_frame = im_util.get_image_relative_to_script('no-data.png')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorboard/plugins/beholder/im_util.py", line 277, in get_image_relative_to_script
    return read_image(filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorboard/plugins/beholder/im_util.py", line 265, in read_image
    return np.array(decode_png(image_file.read()))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorboard/plugins/beholder/im_util.py", line 182, in __call__
    self._lazily_initialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorboard/plugins/beholder/im_util.py", line 160, in _lazily_initialize
    self._session = tf.Session(graph=graph, config=config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1509, in __init__
    super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 638, in __init__
    self._session = tf_session.TF_NewDeprecatedSession(opts, status)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 516, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to create session.
```

TensorBoard worked when I used TensorFlow 1.6 but I think it is not the problem because I tried to re-use the version 1.6 today and it is not working

My folder contains a file "event.out.po", I checked it.

Do you know where is the problem ?

Thank you

Comment: Try using python2.7 version of tensorflow and possibly in an environment like conda,  so that if your run into future problems you can delete the environment and setup a new one. Generally, when you upgrade or downgrade it's not a clean upgrade or downgrade.

Comment: I re-installed  the environnement (Conda and TensorFlow) and it still does not work. Moreover, I configured TensorFlow to use Python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. In the batch before using TensorBoard, this command must be run to use the gpu:

```
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
```

If the precedent command does not work, you can try:

```
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=''
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue but running `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0` before calling `tensorboard` still leaves me with the code above. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I changed it to `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=''` and it worked!

Comment: Good, I edited my answer to add it. Thank you @hubbs5